# What did Professor Eisenstein do to Hitler?

Tags: command-and-conquer

In the opening movie of *Command & Conquer: Red Alert* we see black and white video footage of 2 scientists where one is sitting in the chair before something happens to him. we next see a colour scene and and someone calling out to Hitler who then goes to shake his hand. then their hands touch we see the same sort of effect happen to both the unidentified man and Hitler as what happened to the man that was seated. we are then brought back the previous scene where the seated man seems to "return" and saying that

> Hitler is, out of the way

During the installation sequence of *Command & Conquer: Red Alert 2* it talks about how Professor Eisenstein used his Chronosphere technology to change history which resulted in a power shift where Stalin roses to power and sparked the the events of *Red Alert*, revealing that the seated man is apparently Professor Eisenstein.

However given how i have seen the Chronosphere is used in Red Alert 1 and 2 i don't understand what Professor Eisenstein did to Hitler? like the Chronosphere when used teleport units around the map and even if it was actually sending them back in time allowing them to be re-positioned without hinderence, this wouldn't explain what Eisenstein did when he shook Hitler's hand.

So what did Professor Eisenstein do to Hitler in the opening of *Command & Conquer: Red Alert*?

Comment: I always assumed he just zapped him to kill him off.

Answer (score 2):

It was established in CNC Red Alert 3 that traveling through time and then touching a solid object with your bare skin will ...

> "disrupt the space-time continuum"

... and have a catastrophic effect on the object that has been touched.

---

This is what happened to Hitler when Chrononaut Einstein touched him, and what happens to Einstein a few years earlier/later/whenever when he himself is touched by a Soviet Chrononaut.